# How to setup Magento 2.2 cron job?

Tags: cron, magento2.2, cpanel

I have just made a fresh installation of Magento 2.2.1 to eventually be able to migrate from my present 1.7.

But I already encountered some difficulties. 
The message "One or more indexes are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running." is showing in admin.

I tried to google how to get the cron job running but can't find how to do it in cPanel, and I don't understand how to get it running.
I do not have SSH access and can't do anything through CLI. Does anybody know how I can get this cron thing set up and working from cPanel?

Comment: whether your issue is solved

Answer (score 5):

you can add ssh via cpanel. try this [link](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/enable/)

after ssh is enabled.you have access to your instance, go to the Magento 2 root directory and run `php bin/magento cron:install.`

Comment: @Ronnie79 whether your issue is solved.if solved mark as resolved

Answer (score 3):

You have to have SSH access to your Magento 2 installation in order to run it as smooth as it should. Make sure, you get the access.

As soon as you have access to your instance, go to the Magento 2 root directory and run `php bin/magento cron:install`. That should be enough.

In case the only way for you is to add the cron through an admin interface like cpanel; try to add the cron jobs line by line.

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Depending in the admin panel, you might have to enter the path to the PHP binary. If you are not sure which path it is, just try php.

Comment: Oh. Is there no way to do it in cPanel with Cron Job? Our Host doesn't allow SSH access to anyone for security reasons they say. But our host still offer Magento installation in their installatron...

Comment: Are you able to add CronJobs through the cPanel?

Comment: Can you enter something like `* * * * www-data super_cool_command` somewhere in cPanel?

Comment: Yes, I can add a Cron Job in cPanel. One line command and choose if I want it to be run every minute, every hour etc. But don't know what command to write there to make it work...

Comment: Nice! That is exactly what you need. I'll send you the lines in a few hours.

Comment: I updated the answer and added the lines you'll need. Try to add them one by one. If you are still not sure about it, I would be happy if you can share a screenshot of the cpanel view.

Comment: I finally understood how to run a cron job. :) 

I was not sure if this is the right way but this is how I did it: I created one cron job that run every minute in my cPanel:

/usr/local/bin/php /home/[my username]/domains/[my domain]/public_html/bin/magento cron:install

Then after one minute when I got an email that this was performed I deleted it and created a new one like this instead:

/usr/local/bin/php /home/[my username]/domains/[my domain]/public_html/bin/magento cron:run

Is this correct?

Or should I have the three lines with commands you wrote above running all the time?

Comment: Or du I also need to add 
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log 
and
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log ?

Comment: sry for the late reply. You have to add the three lines that I added above. It is recommended by the Magento 2 devdocs to use all 3 commands.

Answer (score 1):

try this one 
Here are the relevant lines in .htaccess (read the comments):

```
<FilesMatch "^cron.*\.php$">
    ...
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think I sorted it out now.
2. I was not sure if this is the right way but this is how I did it:

I created one cron job that run every minute in my cPanel:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/[my username]/domains/[my domain]/public_html/bin/magento cron:install
```

Then after one minute when I got an email that this was performed I deleted it and created a new one like this instead:

/usr/local/bin/php /home/[my username]/domains/[my domain]/public_html/bin/magento cron:run

Comment: Or do I also need to add * * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log as cron jobs?